# Pass a list of assignments in a template in a flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I try to implement something like `def do_list(resource, elements, template)` which essentially do `return render_template(template, resource = resource_list, "for e in elements, e = e_list")`.

For example, `do_list('activity', ['foo', 'baa'], template)` is `render_template(template, resource = resource_list, foo=foo_list, baa = baa_list)`.

What can I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Jinja templates accept a dict with multiple values. So if you want to pass in a list of values, you should just create a dictionary with the individual keys and values.

Comment: Where is this in the API? Thanks Bhargav

Comment: So you are passing list of lists?. are foo and baa sublists in elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ridiculously Simple:

```
context = {‘foo’: 2, ‘baa’: 3}
return render_template(template, **context)
```

From the thread, [[Flask] Passing dict instead of Context in render_template](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/flask/2016-February/000247.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but the double star method isn't working for me (throwing **`context` is undefined**) with `Flask 0.12.1, Python 3.6.0 (default, Apr 24 2017, 20:55:14)`. Instead, I'm doing it like this: `return render_template(template, context=context)`.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja templates accept a `dict` with multiple values[1]. So if you want to pass in a list of values, you should just create a dictionary with the individual keys and values.

[Here is a blog post](http://blog.mattcrampton.com/post/31254835293/iterating-over-a-dict-in-a-jinja-template) show casing this.

[[1]](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures)